# Im supposed to print a bunch of nodes in a text file but it only prints one number

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, doubly-linked-list

My code is a modification to an existing code that creates a doubly linked list from a series of numbers and prints them in console successfully.  The difference is that my code supposed to take letters and numbers from an input file, put them in the linked list the same way, and print them in an output file going backwards from the last node.

```
public class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node prev;
};
Node start;

(...)

static void display() throws IOException 
    { 
        Node last = (start).prev;
        Node temp = (start).prev;

        File f = new File("STDOUT.txt");
        FileWriter op = new FileWriter(f);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(op);

        while (temp.prev != start) { 
            System.out.printf("%d ", temp.data);
            bw.write(temp.data + " ");
            temp = temp.prev; 
        }
        System.out.printf("%d", temp.data);
        bw.write(temp.data + " ");
        System.out.printf("\nData printed successfully");
        bw.close();
        op.close();

        //function prints single number because it doesn't make new nodes

    } 

    /* Driver code*/
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        Node start = null;
        /* Start with the empty list */
        start = null; 
        char task = 0;
        int value;
        int find;

        try {
            File f = new File("STDIN.txt");
            FileReader op = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(op);
            System.out.println("file located and opened\n");

            br.close();
            op.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("file not located\n");
        }

        File f = new File("STDIN.txt");
        FileReader op = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(op);

        while(task != 'd' && task != 'D') {
            task = (char)br.read();
            if(task == 'b' || task == 'B') {
                br.skip(1);
                value = br.read();
                insertBegin(value);
            }
            else if(task == 'e' || task == 'E') {
                br.skip(1);
                value = br.read();
                insertEnd(value);
            }
            else if(task == 'a' || task == 'A') {
                br.skip(1);
                value = br.read();
                br.skip(1);
                find = br.read();
                insertAfter(value, find);
            }
            else {
                display();
                task = 'd';
            }
        }
        br.close();
        op.close();
    }
```

But the function only prints one number in the function: 52, which isn't even one of the numbers.  Only one node is made and it isn't the right number.  How do I adjust the function or input file so that it puts in the other nodes and prints them the way I want them too?  The input file should look like this:

e 500
b 4
e 70
e 908
a 650 500

and the output should look like this:
908 70 650 500 4

Both these functions are the only one's I've heavily edited but if you need to see the rest of the code to determine my problem, let me know so I show that too.

Comment: 54 is the decimal value for the character '4' - which happens to be the first node.  Include your `Node` definition - you may need to change how you `printf` it.  Your display loop looks odd as well - it starts with `start` node but `while` keeps going until it finds start - makes no sense.

Comment: So what my code does is that it reads the first letter from the input, skips to the second line, reads the second number, sets it's decimal value equal to the value variable, puts that into the first node, reads an incorrect value from the input, stops the loop and prints that one node.  I understand that much but with the way I have it set up, It's supposed to scan every number and letter exactly how it looks in the input file.  I don't know why it does this instead.  @andy

Comment: @Andy also I made a different mistake with the display node.  I wanted it to print the whole list starting from the last node, then stop when it reaches the first node and print that outside the loop.  But if you think it looks wrong, I can probably change the condition of the while loop.